# saving one value in two separate model field drf

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

so I am trying to save same value in two fields in same model .. to give an  example :

my models.py will contain following fields

```
profile_img = models.ImageField("Profile Image", blank=True, null=True)
first_img = models.FileField("First Image", blank=True, null=True)
```

and my serializer.py

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Some
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_img',
        )
```

my views.py

```
class user_api_v2(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SomeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is there any way I can save the same instance of first_img to profile_img while posting ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always write your own create method in the serilaizer class and make it do what you want.

```py
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   ...
   def create(self,validated_data):
      # your code goes here
      # example
      SomeModel.objects.create(profile_img=validated_data['first_img'],
                               first_img=validated_data['first_img'])
      ...
```

docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: Well , It works partially as I have many other fields to populate with . To extend, my model has many more fields and I am populating them with my views